# Battery Charges OK after full discharge, but only once

Tags: battery, charging

I am using a Samsung Galaxy J5 Prime smartphone. My battery recently started to show up (I would plug in the charger, **and it would charge**, but the meter would become stuck). One full discharge solves the problem and the battery charges OK after that, but only once or twice. After that the problem resumes.

I know the battery is being charged because doing a full load drain (screen, flashlight, etc all turned on) takes time to discharge the battery which is already on low percentage so it is definitely a meter fault.

What other options do I have since the full discharge only works once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. See if the behaviour persists in [safe mode](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-g570f-galaxy-j5-prime/faq/safe-mode/)
2. If the behaviour is normal, it would point to a misbehaving app (though, I haven't come across apps causing this). [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) your device​ and check
3. If the same behaviour continued , flash stock ROM using [odin](/questions/tagged/odin), since the fuel gauge drivers may be corrupted

For 2 and 3 make sure you back up your data

If none of above helps, service Center is the only option to address hardware issue

Comment: Apps can't fix this problem